# How to view first Angular template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, templates, url-routing

I'm trying to build a very basic Angular app but I'm having trouble with viewing the first template. My html looks like this:

```
<html ng-app="formApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my `app.js` like this:

```
'use strict';
var formApp = angular.module('formApp', ['ui.router']);
formApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: '/main',
            templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main')
});
```

and my `controllers.js` like this:

```
var formControllers = angular.module('formControllers', []);
formControllers.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.lala = 'lalallala';
});
```

The template under the name `templates/main.html` looks like this:

```
<h1>Yes yes people</h1>
{{lala}}
```

So I started `node` using the command `http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8000` and went in the browser to `http://0.0.0.0:8000/`. Unfortunately, the screen remains white. It does load from the server (I see it making requests to node in the terminal) but I see nothing in the browser. I tried various urls, such as:

```
http://0.0.0.0:8000/
http://0.0.0.0:8000/#
http://0.0.0.0:8000/#/main
http://0.0.0.0:8000/app
http://0.0.0.0:8000/app/#/
```

but nothing works.

Does anybody know how I can view the first template I created? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
The console gives no errors and when I view the source of the page, I do see my html. I just don't see anything like `Yes yes people` which I defined in my main.html. So My template is simply not loading. Any idea?

Comment: First Include app.js

Comment: Check console for errors

Comment: I am not sure. can you try like this:  //0.0.0.0:8000/{your folder name}/app/main

Comment: after rearranging the js files try using `//0.0.0.0:8000/{your folder name}/index.html`

Comment: @soosmca - But isn't the app.js dependent on controllers.js, because (according to the answer by dfsq) I need to provide the `formControllers` as a dependency to the formApp?

Comment: @Nilesh - But if I go to `http://0.0.0.0:8000/` I already see that my index.html is loaded. It just doesn't show the `Yes yes people` which I defined in my `main.html` template. Any idea why the template doesn't load?

Comment: I think it is a problem with `ng-view`. Try using `ui-view` instead as you are using ui-router it should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For UI-Router you should use **ui-view** directive instead of **ng-view**. So your html should look like this:

```
<html ng-app="formApp">
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ui-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome, that was it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you defined controller in separate `formControllers` module, you need to provide it as a dependency to main app module:

```
var formApp = angular.module('formApp', ['ui.router', 'formControllers']);
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Unfortunately I still see a white screen. Any idea what else could be wrong?

Comment: And also, which url should I use?

Comment: Template path should be relative to app base path. Also make sure you use `ui-view`, as pointer in comments by Nilesh.